# how to handle storage in android 11?

Tags: react-native, expo

as we know google after 1st November will only accept apps that target SDK 30 I tried to publish an app with SDK 30 but I was surprised that store data and read it not working, I always get access denied and this problem was fixed in SDK 29 but adding requestlegacyexternalstorage to the application tag

I tried to read the google dev documentation but I couldn't understand that with react native

so I am wondering if someone can help how to work with libraries like react native fetch blob or react native fs in android SDK 30?